Cannot find module "fcm-node" is nodejs ts
I usually use the fcm-node package for sending Firebase push notifications in Node.js. However, this time, I created a TypeScript project and encountered an error.
I am aware that in TypeScript, we need to install type definitions (@types) too. The problem is that when I run npm i @types/fcm-node, it gives me a 404 error. If I’m not mistaken, there are no TypeScript modules available for this package. How can I implement this in TypeScript? Does anyone know of any workarounds? I did try converting my notification.service.ts file to a .js file and used require instead of import in the TypeScript file. This approach worked for npm run dev, but after building with npm run build, when I run dist/index.js, it is unable to find my notification.service.js

If the package lacks TS typings, you have to write them yourself or find one that contains them, it's always as simple as that

@EstusFlask thanks for the reply dude. you might be right i should try writing myself but that will be lot of work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

That's correct, either that, or find another library. This library is outdated and abandoned, this is a reason why there are no third-party types in @types/fcm-node. In case you wondered if there's a shortcut, there's none. Sometimes it's possible to generate .d.ts from cleanly written .js and save on a lot of work, but this is clearly not the case

So after trying a lot, in the end, it turns out that fcm-node doesn’t have types, and writing its type on my own will be a headache. I noticed on the npm website that it has a warning: the package is kind of deprecated because firebase-admin supports push notifications, so it’s better to use it. The only difference is that for fcm-node, we only require the API key, but for firebase-admin, it will require the google-service.json file.
